# Holomorphic function on the Riemann sphere is bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for my probably silly question. Let $f: \mathbb{C}_\infty \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic everywhere, on $\infty$ too. Is it true that $f$ is bounded outside a disk of radius $R>>0$?

My question follows from the following post:

[Is holomorphic function on the Riemann sphere entire?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427079/is-holomorphic-function-on-the-riemann-sphere-entire)

This is fundamental because through it I can prove that every holomorphic function from the Riemann sphere is constant.

Comment: This holds true in even greater generality. Namely, it works if we replace $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ by any connected, compact, complex manifold (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881742/holomorphic-functions-on-a-complex-compact-manifold-are-only-constants), then all holomorphic maps $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are constant.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Riemann sphere is a compact set, any continuous map from it to $\mathbb{C}$ has a compact (hence bounded) image. In particular, if $f$ is holomorphic on the Riemann sphere, it is continuous, hence bounded.

**Edit:** Notice that it is crucial that $f$ is not a map $\mathbb{C}_\infty \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$! Compact sets in the Riemann sphere are not bounded in the traditional sense.

Comment: Not only Riemann sphere compactness is important. It is significant that the mapping operates in $\mathbb C$, not $\mathbb C_{\infty}$.

Comment: Yes, totally! I will edit my answer to stress that fact, thank you!

Comment: Btw what do you mean by "Riemann sphere compactness"? As a subset of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Well you could interpret it like that, yes. The definition of Riemann sphere I know is as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$, by adding the point at $\infty$, and with the correct topology, this makes it compact. A reference I found on wikipedia, if you're interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension

Comment: Ok, but see also the post I've reported in my question. I'd like to understand it works.

Comment: @TheWanderer If the function is bounded on $\mathbb C_{\infty}$, it is also bounded on $\mathbb C$. So we have bounded entire function, it has to be constant according to Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me leave here the solution using only the definition of limit.
We know that $f(z)$ is continuous in $\mathbb C_{\infty}$, it implies $f(z)$ is continuous in $\infty$. By definition it means that if we take $\varepsilon =1$ there exists $R>0$ such that
$$|f(z) -f(\infty)| < \varepsilon=1 \: \forall z: |z| > R$$
Now use triangle inequality, so $\forall z: |z| > R$:
$$|f(z)| - |f(\infty)| \le |f(z) - f(\infty)| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(z)| \le 1 + |f(\infty)|$$
Here it is sufficient that $f$ operates in $\mathbb C$, not $\mathbb C_{\infty}$. It implies that $|f(\infty)|$ is non-negative real number.

We have bounded $f$ outside the circle, inside boundary can be obtained from extreme value theorem about continuous function on compact set (here we have $\{|z| \le R\}$). It says there exists such constant $M > 0$ that:
$$|f(z)|\le M \: \forall z: |z| \le R$$
As a result we have:
$$\forall z\in\mathbb C_{\infty}: |f(z)| \le \max\{1 + |f(\infty)|, M\}$$