# residue computation knowing the limit of $z^2 f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic such that :
$$\lim_{\vert z \vert \rightarrow \infty} z^2f(z) = 0$$
I need to show that $f$ has residue $0$ at $0$ (we are not given the order of the pole.)

Let's say the pole at $0$ has order $n$, my approach originally was to compute this limit : ${Res}(f, a) ={\frac  {1}{(n-1)!}}\lim \limits _{{z\rightarrow a}}{\frac  {\partial ^{{n-1}}}{\partial z^{{n-1}}}}((z-a)^{n}f(z))$ with $a = 0$ but I found the formula for the residue at infinity ${Res} (f,\infty )=\mathrm {Res} \left({-1 \over z^{2}}f\left({1 \over z}\right),0\right)$ which makes a $z^2$ appear, but I don't seem to know how to proceed now. Is this even the right approach ?

Comment: What do you mean under $\mathbb{C}^*$? Is it extended complex plane? If yes, it implies that $f$ is constant. Check this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837641/holomorphic-function-on-the-riemann-sphere-is-bounded/4837668#4837668)

Comment: Sorry, $\mathbb{C}^*$ stands for $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The function $g(\zeta)=-\frac{1}{\zeta^2}f\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)$ is defined for $\zeta\neq 0$ and is holomorphic there, and $g(\zeta)\to 0$ as $\zeta\to 0$, meaning $g$ extends holomorphically to $\zeta=0$. So, what is the residue of $g$ at $0$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: The residue of $g$ at $0$ corresponds to the residue of $f$ at $\infty$, but the question askes for the residue of $f$ at $0$. Those two residues are closely related, of course.

Comment: @MartinR yup I know, but given that OP already brought this up, I wanted to help them follow it through. Of course, as you say, once we figure out $\text{Res}(f,\infty)=\text{Res}(g,0)$, we can figure out $\text{Res}(f,0)=\text{Res}(g,\infty)$, since the sum of residues must be $0$ (we can apply this statement to either $f$ or $g$, though I’d rather apply it to $g$, since it extends to be entire). But of course, one can avoid all these mental gymnastics and follow your suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

The residue at the origin is
$$
 \operatorname{Res}(f, 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma f(z) \, dz
$$
for any positively oriented simple closed curve around the origin.

Choose $\gamma$ as a circle with center $0$ and “large” radius  $R> 0$ and use the property $\lim_{\vert z \vert \rightarrow \infty} z^2f(z) = 0$ to conclude that the residue is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Write out the Laurent series for $f$ as
$f(z) = \big(\sum_{k=-3}^{-\infty} a_k z^k\big)  +\big(\sum_{k=-2}^\infty a_k z^k\big)$, where $a_{-1}$ is the residue

define entire function $h$ given by $h(z):=\sum_{k=-2}^\infty a_k z^{k+2}$
$\implies h(z)=z^2\cdot f(z) -\big(\sum_{k=-3}^{-\infty} a_k z^{k+2}\big)$, for $z\in\mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$
$\implies \lim_{z\to\infty} h(z)=\lim_{z\to\infty}z^2\cdot f(z) -\lim_{z\to\infty}\big(\sum_{k=-3}^{-\infty} a_k z^{k+2}\big)=0-0=0$
The above limit tells us $h$ is bounded hence Liouville applies and we conclude $h$ is constant and in particular the residue $a_{-1}=0$